# `FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/content/Weeds_Detectiontrain/1.png'` How to write the correct directory

Tags: python-3.x, image, for-loop

I'm new to python! I am trying to upgrade myself. However, I have a dataset namely tree_dataset which contains 3 folders i.e. test, train, and validation. Each folder contains 9 different folders (classes). Now, I want to show a sample of all first images (data) from the 9 different classes.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
import os
import imageio
import skimage
import skimage.io
import skimage.transform


# Showing sample of all first images (data) from the 09 different classes

f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=9, figsize=(20, 10))
i=0
for d in directory:
    file='/content/tree_dataset'+d+'/1.png'
    im=imageio.imread(file)
    ax[i].imshow(im,resample=True)
    ax[i].set_title(d, fontsize=8)
    i+=1
```

Error: `FileNotFoundError: No such file: '/content/Weeds_Detectiontrain/1.png'`

Comment: That slash in the front will search for the file starting at your document root, which is probably not what you want. If you want to start from your working directory, put a period at the front of that, e.g. `./content/Weeds_Detectiontrain/1.png` or `file='./content/tree_dataset'+d+/1.png'`

Comment: What kind of period do I need to put before `/content?`. I put . before /content but it is still error. @David